# How flash dispatchEvent really works?

Tags: events, flash, dispatchevent

It is said in the [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#dispatchEvent%28%29), that EventDispatcher's dispatchEvent "...dispatches an event into the event flow". The phrase is nice-looking and doesn't really explain anything.

Say, we have two listeners waiting for an event "A" on object "a", so what behaviour do we have to expect on calling:

a.dispatchEvent("A")?

Would both listeners be called immediately, before return from distpatchEvent? Or they will be queued in some internal flash player queue and will be processed by entering the next frame? Can we rely on some defined behaviour of flash player here or the behaviour is undefined? How one should read "dispatches an event to event flow"? The question is important since in practice it affects the control flow of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Signals instead :P

https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals/wiki

No but really, they're very easy to use and understand, a great addition to the AS3 toolbox.

You can also learn a lot about how native AS3 events work by reading Rob Penner's critiques (scroll down to bottom of wiki page)

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your display list hierarchy.

Flash's event structure is based on its [internal event model](http://books.google.ca/books?id=gUHX2fcLKxYC&lpg=PP1&dq=essential%20actionscript%203.0&pg=PA504#v=onepage&q&f=false).

1. The Stage will be the first object
   notified, and then the event will
   trickle down the display list until
   it reaches its target. This phase is
   called the **capture phase**. To enable it, set `useCapture` to
   `true` on an event listener. Do note
   that it's pointless to do so unless
   the object listening is a parent of
   the object targeting the event. This
   is called **event intercepting**.
2. The next phase is the **target
   phase**. This is the behavior most
   commonly known with events. The
   targeted display object (the one the
   has a listener for the event) will
   receive the event and carry out the
   code in the listener.
3. The final phase is called the
   **bubbling phase**. This is when the event bubbles up the display list
   *after* the event has been received. Event bubbling is very important for
   dispatching custom events, as you'll
   need to know how to listen for
   events dispatched by an object's
   children.

When dispatching an event, I generally use this syntax (`Event.CHANGE` is just a common example):

`Object.dispatchEvent(new Event("CHANGE", true, false));`

The `Object` is the object you're dispatching from. The first parameter is the event you're dispatching. The second is the `bubbles` parameter. The final is the `cancelable` property. `Event.cancelable` is used to prevent the default action of an event (IE: a mouse click) via `Event.preventDefault()`.

Reference:

- [Chapter 21 of Colin Moock's
  Essential Actionscript 3.0](http://books.google.ca/books?id=gUHX2fcLKxYC&lpg=PP1&dq=essential%20actionscript%203.0&pg=PA502#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- [EventDispatcher.dispatchEvent()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#dispatchEvent%28%29)
- [Event.cancelable](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html#cancelable)